# creating database for Calendar

Tags: database, codeigniter, calendar

I am creating a calendar by using codeigniter but in my project there are many users and each user need to have separate calendar. How can I design the database?

Comment: I know how to create database for one user and I created it. But if there are two users, I need two separate calendars, and that is the problem how can I create the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a similar project. In my case, each user will have an agenda so I need to store lots of dates of different users. What I will be doing is that I will create a table for users with their general info and set as primary key their "emailAddress". So for every user I will create a separate table with the title of their "emailAddress" or maybe some other ID# to identify the table and relate it to the user, here I'll store all their dates. I might end up with hundreds of theses tables, but at least I will have a good order on the dates that I will be storing. I hope this helps give you a better idea.